# chart-js - npm install show version conflicts

Tags: npm, chart.js

after the clone of the latest 4.1.2 version of Chart.js I tried to set up the environment using
npm install the result is a version conflict

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

details see below.

from my understanding the rollup installation should work "^3.x.x" === ">=3.x.x" so 3.9.1 should fit (https://github.com/isaacs/node-semver "^3.3.0" === "3.3.0" <= V < 4.x.x)
rollup-7.0.2 will not fit ("^2.0.0" <= V <= "3.x.x" < 7.x.x)

If I do this using npm install --legacy-peer-deps the result is a deprecated package message-

npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

Details below.

It is ubuntu server 22.04LTS with nodes (incl. npm) from nodesource (node 18.12.1, npm 8.19.2).

Any hints are welcome.

I did

npm install

result:
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: chart.js@4.1.2
npm ERR! Found: rollup@3.9.1
npm ERR! node_modules/rollup
npm ERR!   dev rollup@"^3.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer rollup@"^2.0.0" from rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/rollup-plugin-terser
npm ERR!   dev rollup-plugin-terser@"^7.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

and
npm install --legacy-peer-deps